# Normalise JSON object key names

Tags: javascript, json

I am wanting to write a function to turn a JSON object's keys into more appropriate names. As you can see by the JSON object below, the keys are 1 letter and are not very readable or useful for anyone. Therefore I would like to loop through the object (or something similar) and rename all the keys, and then return this JSON.

```
{
    "e": "56049",
    "pp": "371861",
    "c": "GAME",
    "x": 2,
    "st": "2017-04-27T15:01:29Z",
    "o": 0,
    "r": true,
    "u": "2017-04-27T15:01:29Z",
    "t": "p",
    "i": "371871",
    "z": 1493305289586
}
```

Comment: A non-programmer style answer: search&replace in the JSON file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) object keys to new object, e.g.:

```
const obj = {
  "e": "56049",
  "pp": "371861",
  "c": "GAME",
  "x": 2,
  "st": "2017-04-27T15:01:29Z",
  "o": 0,
  "r": true,
  "u": "2017-04-27T15:01:29Z",
  "t": "p",
  "i": "371871",
  "z": 1493305289586
}

// [key] -> [normalized name] mapping
const names = {
  "e": "e-name",
  "pp": "pp-name",
  "c": "c-name",
  "x": "x-name",
  "st": "st-name",
  "o": "o-name",
  "r": "r-name",
  "u": "u-name",
  "t": "t-name",
  "i": "i-name",
  "z": "z-name"
}

const renamedProps = Object.keys(obj).reduce((renamed, key) => {
  renamed[names[key]] = obj[key];
  return renamed;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
        "e": "56049",
        "pp": "371861",
        "c": "GAME",
        "x": 2
    },
    names = ["e_new-name", "pp_new-name", "c_new-name", "x_new-name"],
    updated = {},
    keys = Object.keys(obj);

for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    updated[names[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(updated));
// will print
// {"e_new-name":"56049","pp_new-name":"371861","c_new-name":"GAME","x_new-name":2}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/nf8ydopw/)